# Magento2 remove .html from parent category url

Tags: magento2

I am facing an issue in my Magento2 store, as my subcategory Url is loading as http://example.com/category.html/subcategory.html.Is there a way that i can change it to http://example.com/category/subcategory.html?

Comment: i think may be you add url key of parent category as category.html...check it.

Comment: Thanks for the info,i had added as parent category as category only in url key

Comment: check this Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Category URL Suffix to remove .html you can change configuration and save it.